# Display all local variables within a edebug session

Tags: debugging, variables, local-variables, edebug

When using edebug one can get a local variable by command `describe-variable` (`C-h v`), but are there any ways to display all *local* variables?

For example in Python you can call `locals()` in a `pdb` session, which returns all the local vars in dictionary. Does Elisp have a similar function?

Comment: You may be interested in function `backtrace--locals`, however, double hyphen suggests it's not intended for use by other packages. I.e. I would advise against using it in your ELisp programs, since the API may change, or the function will be removed entirely.

Comment: Plain `debug` has `debugger-toggle-locals` (bound to `v`), not sure about edebug.

Comment: locals arent displayed as in let forms with C-h v. need to use "e" to evaluate.