# Why is it that during debugging EDebug says local variable is not bound?

Tags: variables, edebug

For example, I debug a function, I'm stepping in it, I want to check a local variable's value and `C-h v` says: variable is not bound

I can eval the variable, by pressing `e` and tpying its name, only `describe-variable` can't pick it up.

Why is that? I seem to remember it worked fine in the past when I used debugging.

It's Emacs 27.

Comment: If you mean "local" as in "buffer-local" then remember that `C-h v` shows you the binding for the buffer in which you are typing `C-h v` (so if that's the debugger's buffer, you wouldn't expect it to have the same value).

Comment: I took `local` to mean `let-bound` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that has always been the case: variables that are let-bound in a function are not known to the `C-h v` (aka `describe-variable`) mechanism. I don't think `edebug` does anything to change this.

Try the following experiment:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (let ((bar "baz"))
    (setq bar "hunoz")
    (princ bar)
    (describe-variable 'bar)))
```

When you call the function with `(foo)` in the `*scratch*` buffer, you get the most recent value  printed out (`hunoz`), but `describe-variable` does not know about it, so the return value of `foo` (which is what the `describe-variable` call returns) says that `bar is void as a variable`:

```
hunoz#("bar is void as a variable.

Not documented as a variable.

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 16.

" 108 110 (button (t) category help-news-button help-args ("/usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.50/etc/NEWS.1-17" 43356)))
```

OTOH, if you try

```el
(defun foo ()
  (let ((bar "baz"))
    (setq bar "hunoz")
    (princ bar)
    (describe-variable 'bar)
    (describe-variable 'major-mode)
    ))
```

the same value is printed out, but the return value now is what the last call of `describe-variable` returns which is the description of `major-mode`:

```
hunoz#("major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is ‘lisp-interaction-mode’
Original value was ‘fundamental-mode’
Local in buffer *scratch*; global value is fundamental-mode

Symbol for current buffer’s major mode.
The default value (normally ‘fundamental-mode’) affects new buffers.
A value of nil means to use the current buffer’s major mode, provided
it is not marked as \"special\".

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  You can customize this variable.

" 37 50 (help-args (major-mode C-source) category help-variable-def-button button (t)) 458 467 (help-args (major-mode) category help-customize-variable-button button (t)))
```

That shows that `edebug` has nothing to do with it.

EDIT: It seems that the behavior the OP describes was lost when lexical binding became the default for let-bound variables. As @phils says in a comment:

> `describe-variable` is looking at the symbol (there's a `boundp` call), so a lexically-bound value is invisible to it. So I think this sounds normal. Under dynamic binding if I call `(debug)` or `(recursive-edit)` then I can see the let-bound value via its symbol.

EDIT: in order to evaluate expresssions in `Edebug`, use `e <EXP>` (you can use minibuffer history with `M-n/M-p` to avoid typing an expresssion more than once) or `C-x C-e` for the expression before point - see [Edebug eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug-Eval.html).

Comment: Check out this older questions, it says "When using edebug one can get a local variable by command describe-variable (C-h v)" , so clearly the asker used C-h v for that and I too seem to remember doing it. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35732/display-all-local-variables-within-a-edebug-session

Comment: It may be that the lexical scoping changes changed what `describe--variable` can do. But we'll have to wait for somebody who is au courant with those changes to tell us. Maybe @Drew or @phils will be able to enlighten us.

Comment: Yes, `describe-variable` is looking at the symbol (there's a `boundp` call), so a lexically-bound value is invisible to it.  So I think this sounds normal.  Under dynamic binding if I call `(debug)` or `(recursive-edit)` then I can see the `let`-bound value via its symbol.

Comment: If this is the case then what is the recommended way of inspecting the value of a variable under the cursor in  edebug which does not involve typing its name manually?  It's such a basic operation for debugging, where one often inspects variables, there must be some way to do it.

Comment: I think your options are `e` (or `R`) and `v` (or `C-u v`).  Not specifically what you're asking, but the latter doesn't involve much typing, and you can use history as normal with the former.  (I never do a ton with the standard debugger, so that's all I know.  Be sure to check the manual.)

Comment: `e` with hostory and `C-x C-e` for the expression before point work in Edebug. I added an edit to the answer with these.

Answer (score 0):

locals and let bound can be examined using "e" for edebug-eval-expression

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25685)